# Getting error when integrating binary framework in SPM, Does not contain expected binary artifact

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I am creating an SPM using the binary framework. I upload a zip file on the server and that link is used in SPM.

```
let package = Package(
name: "MyDemoPackage",
platforms: [
    .iOS(.v13)
],
products: [
    
    .library(
        name: "MyDemoPackage",
        targets: ["MyDemoPackage"]),
],
dependencies: [
    
],
targets: [
    
    .binaryTarget(
        name: "MyDemoPackage",
        url:"https:domain.com/frameork.zip",
        checksum: "29725502a0b4e61c375f71eec3d5432ac84c")           
]
)
```

After compilation shows an error

> Showing Recent Messages
> downloaded archive of binary target 'MyDemoPackage' does not contain expected binary artifact 'MyDemoPackage'.

I am unable to figure out how to resolve this error. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is there a missing `w` in the url spelling?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I know w is missing, it's just the framework name.

Comment: Did you find any solutions. I'm facing same issue. If I use framework locally or package it with Swift Package it works fine. But when I use url it displays same error.

Answer (score 4):

Binary Target name should match the name of the module defined by xcframework.

Comment: To clarify "module" here, I build `PopH264.xcframework` which contains `PopH264_Osx.framework` and `PopH264_ios.framework`. My `binarytarget()` `.name` had to be `PopH264`

Comment: The module name is encoded into machO binary. The good way to check the right module name is to link the sample project against the framework and import its module (aka import SomeModule). Then name the target name accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This may also happen if you have used `ditto` without --keepParent argument to compress the framework. [source](https://forums.swift.org/t/debugging-does-not-contain-expected-binary-artifact-error/58870/3)